# Local Extremes and Differentiable Functions

Tags: calculus, functions

A local extreme value is found in the interior domain of a differentiable function. A claim is made that the curve must have a positive slope on one side of the extreme and a negative slope on the other side of the extreme. Some say that it does not have to be that way. Which claim is true?

Comment: Take a constant function.

Answer (score 1):

By the [Interior extremum theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_theorem_%28stationary_points%29), a local extrema of a differentiable must occur when the derivative is 0. Let $x_0$ be the location of the extrema and $a<x_0$ and $b>x_0$ and $f$ be the function.

By the first derivative test, if $f'(a)>0$ and $f'(b)<0$ then $x_0$ is a local max. If  $f'(a)<0$ and $f'(b)>0$ then $x_0$ is a local min. Therefore, having exhausted the types of extrema, we conclude the curve must have a positive slope on one side of the extreme and a negative slope on the other side of the extreme.